# Modify Latest Blog Posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

The basic 'Latest Blog Posts' in WP just gives the name. I would also like to have the author and date it was created. How can I easily do this in WP? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wordpress Codex: [Author Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) and [Post Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section)